# What is the most efficient approach in a React Redux project that uses aggressive composition?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-redux, composition

I'm developing a project that uses **aggressive composition** (each component will have lots of components in its tree and each of its components will have a significant number of components as well) and uses **Redux** to manage the state.

For example:

```
<ComponentA>
  <ComponentB>
    <ComponentC>
      ...
           <ComponentZ>
           </ComponentZ>
    </ComponenetC>
  </ComponentB>
</ComponentA>
```

Each of these components will have **their own functions** that can change the app's state.

What would be the most efficient approach to manage all the functions that change the state in the application?

-Use a Container component that connects ComponentA with the actions and pass all the functions down in the components tree

Example:

```
<ComponentA
  funcB={this.props.funcB}
  funcC={this.props.funcC}
  ...
  funcZ={this.props.funcZ}
>
```

-Each component has it's own container so fewer functions will be passed down in the components tree but each component will need an additional component to have the connection:

```
<ContainerA>
  <ContainerB>
    ...
      <ContainerZ />
  </Container>
</ContainerA>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to connect a parent to Redux and let the connected parent drive its children so that children became aware of Redux store changes via the props passed to them by the parent. And change the store by calling parent's methods passed as props. However the grandkids of the connected parent would connect to Redux store themselves but not their children and so forth.

> Each of these components will have their own functions that can change the app's state.

If their own functions change their own subset (or slice) of Redux store which other components don't need to be aware of and if the overall store is too big then you can consider splitting it into several independent stores. [Link](https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps)